# How to make a discord bot only rspond to a command from a certain rank

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have a discord bot already in place on my server using python, anyone can join my server and use the bot, but I only want specific commands able to be used by our mods role. So, if someone just entered the server, they cant use a command that shows a bunch of info that only a mod should see, but can use one that plays trivia or something with them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a decorator `@has_permission`.

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import has_permission

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@has_permission(administrator=True)
async def some_command(ctx):
    # something to do.
```

There are several permissions, and you can see them at [here](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/discord/permissions.py). All `@property` can be used as a permission.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually access the message author's roles through context.

Here is an example:

```
async def command_for_mods(ctx, further_arguments):
    if "moderator" in [i.name.lower() for i in ctx.author.roles]:
        # Do things only moderators can do
    else:
        # Tell the user they don't have the moderator role or pass
```

Please let me know if there are any errors, for I may be inaccurate.